# Unable to access Google Cloud Secrets from Django application

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, gcp-secrets-manager

I am able to access an item stored in Google Cloud secrets from the command line or python console -

```
gcloud secrets versions access 1 --secret=sql-db-pass
```

But if I try to access it from a Django application it throws the following error. I have already set the gcloud project and provided auth-default login as below

```
gcloud config set project my-test-project

gcloud auth application-default login
```

**CODE:**

```
secret_parent = "projects/my-test-project"
response = secret_client.access_secret_version(request={"name": "sql-db-pass"})
payload = response.payload.data.decode("UTF-8")
print(f"Plaintext: {payload}")
```

**ERROR:**

```
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission denied on resource project sql-db-pass. [links {
  description: "Google developers console"
  url: "https://console.developers.google.com"
}
, reason: "CONSUMER_INVALID"
domain: "googleapis.com"
metadata {
  key: "service"
  value: "secretmanager.googleapis.com"
}
metadata {
  key: "consumer"
  value: "projects/sql-db-pass "
}
]
```

I'm stumped - any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Use the Project ID and not the Project Name. The key error message is `CONSUMER_INVALID`.

Comment: You are absolutely spot on! Looks like the API requires the ID and not the name. So I was able to get past this initial error by replacing `my-test-project` with the corresponding ID. Now it gives me the same error for the secret ID - `sql-db-pass` and I am unable to find the ID value of this in the console. Do you happen to know where I can find the same? Thanks a lot...

Comment: What is the error message (exact contents)? Append new details to your post. Note: the correct action is to create a new question. Chaining problems is not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Project ID and not the Project Name.

The key error message is `CONSUMER_INVALID`.